# Unknown display (Nvidia)

Tags: display, resolution

recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer (Nvidia GTX 650 graphics card with a samsung monitor). Problem is when I try to change the resolution, it doesn't recognize my display (Unknown display) and therefore only gives it basic resolution options. I know this has been asked a lot over the internet but everyone says different things and what I tried didn't solve anything.
I tried using this command:
`xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1920x1080/')`
but no new resolution appeared on the `Display` window.
I tried: `xrandr --addmode S-video 1920x1080` But it says it doesn't find S-video, and I don't know what arguments to give it.
I tried disconnecting the monitor for a few seconds then turn it on then run ubuntu, but nothing.
I guess you could say I tried installing Nvidia drivers, but I don't really know how to do this for sure because there are a lot of different ways to do this, I'd appreciate a good guide.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: I now installed the right driver using `Additional Drivers`, display is still unknown.

Thanks.